# Add Google Analytics Annotation via javascript

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-analytics, analytics

Essentially I want to be able to see an annotation on my charts so that I can say "After we sent the EBlast, X happened to Y" (where Y are pageviews, visits, whatever).  Is there a way to do `_gaq.push('[_createAnnotation]')` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to programmatically create new Google Analytics Annotations.

There's an [open issue on the Google Analytics issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=1793) asking that it be made available. It's been starred by 262 people; you can star it to signify that you'd like to see it implemented.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=1793